# How can I disambiguate initializer_lists for constructor calls?

Tags: c++, c++17, initializer-list, variant, class-constructors

I want to be able to initialize `container` with a brace init list and not have to specify types. This is more difficult as I have nested initializers. Now I'm at the point where it almost works, but there are two overloads for initializer_list in the variant wrapper and the compiler can't figure out which to use.

Actually in this case the call is not even ambiguous as only class `keyval` takes a string as its first argument, which means the keyval overload of the variant wrapper should be chosen. But how can I tell this to the compiler?

My code (CompilerExplorer):

```
#include <string>
#include <variant>

template <typename... T> struct vwrapper;

using val = vwrapper<std::monostate, struct array, struct obj, int, bool>;

template <typename... T>
struct vwrapper : public std::variant<T...>
{
    vwrapper(int);
    vwrapper(bool);
    vwrapper(std::initializer_list<struct keyval>);
    vwrapper(std::initializer_list<val>);
    // vwrapper(obj);
    // vwrapper(array);
    vwrapper(std::monostate);
};

struct obj
{
    obj() = default;
    obj(std::initializer_list<struct keyval> init) {

    }
};

struct array
{
    array() = default;
    array(std::initializer_list<val> init) {

    }
};

struct keyval
{
    keyval() = default;
    keyval(std::string, val);
};

template <typename... T>
vwrapper<T...>::vwrapper(int) {}

template <typename... T>
vwrapper<T...>::vwrapper(bool) {}

template <typename... T>
vwrapper<T...>::vwrapper(std::initializer_list<val>) {}

template <typename... T>
vwrapper<T...>::vwrapper(std::initializer_list<struct keyval>) {}

// template <typename... T>
// vwrapper<T...>::vwrapper(obj) {}

// template <typename... T>
// vwrapper<T...>::vwrapper(array) {}

keyval::keyval(std::string str, val value) {  }

struct container : public array, public obj
{
    using array::array;
    using obj::obj;
};


int main()
{
    container some_container = { 1, 2, true, false, 2, { { "hello", 2 }, { "mogli", true }}};
}
```

Comment: Off topic: there is no need to specify `struct` before `array`, because this is C++.

Comment: @康桓瑋 There is, that serves as a forward declaration.

Comment: @康桓瑋 It is necessary here because this is an in place forward declaration

Comment: Oops, my oversight, the first thing I saw was `vwrapper<T...>::vwrapper(std::initializer_list<struct keyval>)`, which was already after the `keyval` definition. I think the simplest answer should be specify the type of `keyval` only once eg `{ keyval{ "hello", 2 }, { "mogli", true }}`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 That works of course but I wanted the API to not be dependent on that...

Answer (score 2):

A *minimal* version of your snippet is

```
#include<initializer_list>

struct val
{
    val(int);
    val(bool);
    val(std::initializer_list<struct keyval>);
    val(std::initializer_list<val>);
};

struct keyval
{
    keyval(const char*, val);
};

struct container
{
    container(std::initializer_list<val>);
    container(std::initializer_list<keyval>);
};

void foo()
{
    container{{"", 2}, {"", true}};
}
```

At which point the ambiguity presents itself: a string literal is convertible to a `bool`. Both `val{"", 2}` and `keyval{"", 2}` are valid expressions, with the first being interpreted as

```
val{std::initializer_list<val>{val{bool("")}, val{2}}}
```

To avoid the ambiguity, force the type to be `keyval`

```
container{keyval{"", 2}, {"", true}};
```

Comment: Thanks but that's exactly what I wanted to avoid when I said "...and not have to specify types". Is there any other way? And how on earth are string literals convertible to bool? That doesn't seem very intuitive.

Comment: @glades You may replace `container(std::initializer_list<val>);` with `template<typename... Ts> container(Ts&&...);` (also for `val` constructor), which may or may not fit your use case. The conversion is through decaying to a pointer then to bool.